# How can calculate f?

Tags: matlab

I have a loop, in each iteration I want to compute $f(X)$ such that $X$ is a vector.

When I wrote `f=@(x,y) (x+2)^2+(y-x)^3` and `X=[1,5]`,
I have an error in `f(X)`.

How can write  function $f(X)$ such that  $X$ can be a vector?

And suppose we  can't use  `f(X(1),X(2))`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
>> f=@(x,y) (x+2)^2+(y-x)^3;
X=[1,5];
f(X)
Error using  ^ 
One argument must be a square matrix and the other must be
a scalar. Use POWER (.^) for elementwise power.
Error in @(x,y)(x+2)^2+(y-x)^3
```

you might try using

```
>> f=@(X) (X(1)+2)^2+(X(2)-X(1))^3;
X=[1,5];
f(X)
ans =
    73
```

Comment: hello thanks;-)

Comment: You're welcome!